# How can I dynamically resize an image in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, dynamic, resize, image-manipulation

#### Question

How can I dynamically resize an image in ASP.NET MVC?

#### Background

I'm trying to automatically create thumbnails from images that are already on the server. In ASP.NET Webforms, I created a `HTTPHandler` to do this and added verbs in the `web.config` for all image extensions to pass through the handler. The handler was nice in that if you wanted the original image, you'd use a typical image tag:

`<img src="pic.jpg"/>`

But if you wanted a resized image, you'd use:

`<img src="pic.jpg?width=320&height=240"/>`

Is there a way to duplicate the same behavior in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Unlike an HttpHandler, a HttpModule will work seamlessly with both MVC and WebForms. The most popular image resizing HttpModule for ASP.NET is http://imageresizing.net . It's free, open-source, and foolproof.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Unfortunately, imageresizing.net wasn't around in 2009 when I asked the question.

Comment: It was, actually. Been around since 2007. But in all fairness, it didn't get to page 1 of google till early 2009...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely reuse the same `IHttpHandler`. You just need a new [IRouteHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.iroutehandler.aspx) to map the incoming request to the correct handler:

```
public class ImageRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new YourImageHttphandler();
    }
}
```

In your routes, add:

```
routes.Add("Images", new Route("images/{*file}", new ImageRouteHandler()));
```

Now any request in `/images` (e.g. `/images/pic.jpg?width=320&height=240`) will be handled by your existing handler. Obviously you can change the route pattern to match any path that makes sense, just like a typical MVC route.

Comment: Will this code work for subdirectories under the images folder?

Comment: @DanielT yes! See the tiny edit to my answer - adding the asterisk to `{*file}` will have that route catch everything under /images, including subdirectories.

Comment: Hmm, slight problem: this routing only works if I manually type the URL into the address bar, like so: `http://localhost:4692/Content/images/IMG_0146.JPG`. However, I need to embed the image inside a View, and it doesn't go through the routing handler since it's already been routed to the controller.

Comment: @DanielT hmm, not sure what you mean. Each resource on the page, such as `<img src...`, is sent to the server by the browser as a distinct request, and each will be handled separately. Can you describe what you're seeing in more detail?

Comment: What about images that are in CSS as background images?

Answer (score 13):

Using `WebImage` class that comes in [`System.Web.Helpers.WebImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) you can achieve this.

You can use this great kid to output resized images on the fly.

Sample code:

```
public void GetPhotoThumbnail(int realtyId, int width, int height)
{
    // Loading photos’ info from database for specific Realty...
    var photos = DocumentSession.Query<File>().Where(f => f.RealtyId == realtyId);

    if (photos.Any())
    {
        var photo = photos.First();

        new WebImage(photo.Path)
            .Resize(width, height, false, true) // Resizing the image to 100x100 px on the fly...
            .Crop(1, 1) // Cropping it to remove 1px border at top and left sides (bug in WebImage)
            .Write();
    }

    // Loading a default photo for realties that don't have a Photo
        new WebImage(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Content/images/no-photo100x100.png")).Write();
}
```

In a view you'd have something like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetPhotoThumbnail",
     new { realtyId = item.Id, width = 100, height = 100 })" />
```

More about it here: [Resize image on the fly with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.leniel.net/2012/04/resize-img-on-fly-aspnet-webimage.html)

There's also a great tutorial on the ASP.NET site: [Working with Images in an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Site](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/files,-images,-and-media/9-working-with-images).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in mvc. You can either use a httphandler as you did before or you create an action that streams the resized image.

If it were me I would create a controller with a resize method.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you said about creating an action that streams the resized image?

Comment: Wait, I think I get it. You mean to use RedirectToAction("Thumbnail") that returns a thumbnail, right?

Comment: I'm not at my computer, but there is a "Content" method that streams data. I believe it has a signature that takes a stream or byte array and then has a paramenter for content type. For the content type you would pass "image/jpg." Then all you need is to reference the action in an HTML image element.

Comment: The above assumes you already have the resized the image in memory as a stream oy byte[]

Comment: I'd very much prefer the view to resize the image. My opinion is that the controller should only give the view a 'table' of data to display, in this case, a list of all the images that match a criteria, and it's the view's job to handle the image resizing, if necessary.

Comment: If you are going to downvote an answer, it's courtesy is leave a comment. It's a bit absurd to downvote an answer written 3 years ago. Move value is added by providing your own answer.